# Is there a way to send data from HTML (using ejs template engine) to Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am currently working on my self-project using Node.Js (Express) + MongoDB + Javascript/Jquery + HTML (using EJS as my template engine).

Currently I have some knowledge of sending data from Node.js router to Views and sending form data from Views back to router using "POST" and "GET" method.

I was wondering if there are other methods of sending a data from Views to Node.js router without going through

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

methods...

I have no knowledge on Angular2 and REACT..

For example, I am trying to send back the updated data from Views (probably using Jquery's editable() plugin to simply edit a text that was generated from MongoDB and send the updated contents back to server so I could update MongoDB 
 and save contents based on updated contents.

I feel like using a form should be only done once when I want to add new stuffs into DB...please help me out! Some of the stuffs I am asking are vague but these are the best I can explain. Or learning Angular2 is the best approach Lol ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you referring to Ajax requests? I mean, there's forms, Ajax, and WebSockets/etc. Not many other options for talking back to the server side. Regardless of what client-side framework you wrap it up in.

Comment: I think it is AJAX that I am looking for! Maybe I've been thinking too complicate to solve my issues. So if I make a AJAX call from client side to server, server can receive data right?

Comment: yes, you'd make a POST with some data. that can be solved with jQuery, axios or the new html5 stuff(opposite of fetch, dont remember the name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to learn about $.ajax (if you're using Jquery) or XMLHttpRequest (if you aren't).  That is significantly more versatile than forms (though you still should use a form to hold the entry fields; just don't give it an action if you're using a JavaScript-based AJAX call instead).

If updating an existing entry, you probably want the PUT method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I think AJAX is what I am looking for! I have some exposure to AJAX but completely forgotten about it!